# Why generic type lookup is not allowed at runtime in Java?

Tags: java, generics, type-erasure

I am trying to see if it possible to get object type for a generic class at run-time in Java.

**Example:**

```
public class Member<T> {

    private T id;
    private T complexityLevel;

    // constructor
    public Member(T id, T complexityLevel) {
        this.id = id;
        this.complexityLevel = complexityLevel;
    }

    // getters and setters goes here
}
```

*Testing..*

```
public class TestDrive {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Member<String> memberString = new Member<String>("1", "100");
        Member<Integer> memberInteger = new Member<Integer>(1, 100);
        Member<Double> memberDouble = new Member<Double>(1.0, 100.00);

        List<Member<?>> members = new ArrayList<>();
        members.add(memberString);
        members.add(memberInteger);
        members.add(memberDouble);

        for (Member<?> aMember : members) {
            if (aMember.getClass().isInstance(String.class))
                System.out.printf("String member is found with id: " + aMember.getId());
            else if (aMember.getClass().isInstance(Integer.class))
                System.out.printf("Integer member is found with id: " + aMember.getId());
            else if (aMember.getClass().isInstance(Double.class))
                System.out.printf("Double member is found with id: " + aMember.getId());
        }
    }
}
```

Is it possible to get wrapper classes (`String`, `Integer`, `Double` etc) for objects of `Member` class at run-time?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't determine generic types at runtime due to [type erasure](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/erasure.html). In order for this information to be preserved after erasure, `Member<T>` would need to take a `Class<T>` object in its contructor and hold onto it:

```
public class Member<T> {

public final Class<T> type;

private T id;
private T complexityLevel;

//constructor   
public Member(T id, T complexityLevel, Class<T> type) {
   id = id;
   this.complexityLevel = complexityLevel;
   this.type = type;
}
```

Then later:

```
Member<String> mString = new Member<String>("id1", "High", String.class);

...

System.out.println(mString.type.getName());
```

Alternatively, if `id` is guaranteed never to be `null`, you could use reflection to retrieve the `Class` object representing its type:

```
System.out.println(mString.getId().getClass().getName());
```

Of course [getClass()](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#getClass%28%29) will return a `Class<? extends T>`. So if `id` is in fact a subclass of `T`, you're going to get the name of that class rather than the name of `T`.

Comment: @neal_fazio - Are you asking how to get just "String", "Integer" etc? You can use `getSimpleName()` instead of `getName()`.

Answer (score 3):

This information (the generic type T) is stripped out during compilation (type erasure).

Using [super type tokens](http://gafter.blogspot.com/2006/12/super-type-tokens.html) is a moderately painful technique that can apply here. Guice's [TypeLiteral](https://google-guice.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/javadoc/com/google/inject/TypeLiteral.html) is an example of this.

Also, String and Integer are not primitive types. "int" is a primitive.